# Pig latin: How to interact with previous rows

Tags: apache-pig

I have this text:

```
1438675200,userId
1438675500,userId
1438675800,userId
1438676100,userId
1438676400,userId
```

First field is epoch timestamp, second field is userId.

How can i use pig to get the timestamp of the current row extract timestamp of the previous row ?

Comment: google `apache pig windowing functions` http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html

Comment: Your comment is the answer !